# Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am getting this error while adding web support for flutter project. App works on Android and IOS. But while running project on chrome, it loads but shows blank screen.

Chrome Console:

```
errors.dart:266 Uncaught (in promise) Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:266:49)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (platform_channel.dart:294:7)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at async_patch.dart:45:50
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1653:54)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:147:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:766:44)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:795:13)
    at [_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:566:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:639:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider#supported-platforms-and-paths) documentation its clearly mentioned that it only support Android, iOS, Linux, macOS, Windows platforms.

Comment: Can you please tell any alternative of path_provider or other way to getDirectoryPath() for Flutter Web ?

Comment: check out this answer if this can help you https://terabox.com/s/1IRWTMy4Wzl-0N-8ZudxEWA

Comment: Browsers are sandboxed, they don't allow code from an outside soruce access to the file system. There are ways to trigger a browser to upload or download a file (e.g create a ghost anchor to a remote file, and "click" it to download).